# Group and display occurrences of array of hashes based on some key in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
[
  {"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
  {"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
  {"a"=>"second", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
  {"a"=>"third", "b"=>[{"lt"=>9, "lg"=>10}]}
]
```

How can I display occurrences by `"a"` key value and display something like this

```
[
  {{"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>2},
  {{"a"=>"second", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>1},
  {{"a"=>"third", "b"=>[{"lt"=>9, "lg"=>10}]}=>1}
]
```

I am looking for "ruby way" solution.

Comment: I'm assuming the end result is a hash, rather than an array. `=>` would be a syntax error otherwise.

Comment: Sorry I edited! It's an array as well.

Comment: How is it an array if it's described with keys and values? Try to run your expected result in the console. It will create an array with one element with the given keys and values.

Comment: Missed the brackets sorry.

Comment: Very strange conversion. I have updated my answer. Maybe we can help you more if you give us the bigger picture to understand why/if you might need this format.

Comment: What would be the desired result if `lg=>8` were changed to `lg=>9` in the hash that is the first element of the array?

Comment: @CarySwoveland again would be  `{{"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>2}` no matter values of key `"b"` . Just select one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## frequency_distribution

You could define `Enumerable#frequency_distribution` by using [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with a Hash and a default occurence value of `0` :

```
module Enumerable
  def frequency_distribution
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |element, count| count[element] += 1 }
  end
end
```

It works this way :

```
require 'pp'
data = [
    {"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
    {"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
    {"a"=>"second", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
    {"a"=>"third", "b"=>[{"lt"=>9, "lg"=>10}]}
]

pp data.frequency_distribution
# {{"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>2,
#  {"a"=>"second", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>1,
#  {"a"=>"third", "b"=>[{"lt"=>9, "lg"=>10}]}=>1}
```

If you don't want to monkey-patch `Enumerable` :

```
def frequency_distribution(array)
  array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }
end

frequency_distribution(data)
# {{"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>2,
#  {"a"=>"second", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>1,
#  {"a"=>"third", "b"=>[{"lt"=>9, "lg"=>10}]}=>1}
```

Note that the output is one single hash. Keys are hashes and values are integers. I cannot think of any good reason to convert it to an array of 1-pair hashes. Lookup would be much slower and less readable.

## count_by

For a more generic method, you could define `Enumerable#count_by`, with the same syntax as `group_by` or `sort_by` :

```
module Enumerable
  def count_by(&block)
    each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |element, count| count[block.call(element)] += 1 }
  end
end

require 'pp'
data = [
    {"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
    {"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
    {"a"=>"second", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
    {"a"=>"third", "b"=>[{"lt"=>9, "lg"=>10}]}
]

pp data.count_by(&:itself)
# {{"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>2,
#  {"a"=>"second", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]}=>1,
#  {"a"=>"third", "b"=>[{"lt"=>9, "lg"=>10}]}=>1}

pp data.count_by(&:keys)
#=> {["a", "b"]=>4}

pp data.count_by{|key, value| key["a"]}
#=> {"first"=>2, "second"=>1, "third"=>1}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note that it should be much faster than @ndn solution for large arrays.

Comment: And that the result of the two answers is different. 

Comment: True. :) I'm not going to return an array of one-pair hashes. I cannot think of any good reason to do so.

Comment: I would expect a method called `Array#count_by` to take a block, just like the other `..._by` methods. Something like `count_by { |h| h["a"] }` or `count_by(&:itself)`. And it could be defined in `Enumerable`.

Comment: @Stefan : Sorry, that was a mix of old code for similar answers. I updated the answer with `count_by(&block)`.

Comment: Nice! You don't actually need an explicit block variable – `count[yield(e)]` works just as well.

Comment: As a long-standing member the *Less is More Society*, I think your answer would have been better had you simply showed that a counting hash is a short and sweet answer the question, with no monkey-patching extensions that could be used to answer questions that were not asked.

Comment: Sorry, not sorry. I cannot please all the ruby masters on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil what if the array contains `"b"` key values which are different for different elements something like this `{"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>8}]},
  {"a"=>"first", "b"=>[{"lt"=>7, "lg"=>9}]}` but need to save one of them doesn't matter.

Comment: @arm2pro What would be the desired behaviour? Those 2 hashes are different, so would have both a count of `1`. With `count_by`, you could define the desired behaviour, though.

Comment: I am trying to group by values of key `a`.  So for the above example I would get one hash with count 2. No matter if their `b` values are different.

Comment: See last example.

Answer (score 2):

```
foos.map { |foo| {foo => foos.count(foo)} }.uniq
```

Comment: With `foos = [1]*10`, it parses the array 100 times and creates 10 times the exact same `[1, 10]` array...

Comment: @EricDuminil, so it does. Also it's `O(n^2)` and not `O(n)`.

Comment: Perfect! That was I looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question, it has nothing to do with the particular elements of your given array. More generally, given an array

```
arr = [a,a,b,c]
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are *any* Ruby objects, you want a count of each unique element, expressed as an array of hashes. To keep things simple, suppose

```
arr = [1,1,2,3]
```

Here are two ways to obtain the counts by making a single pass through `arr`.

```
arr.group_by(&:itself).map { |k,v| { k=>v.size } }
  #=> [{ 1=>2 }, { 2=>1 }, { 3=>1 }]
```

and (a *counting hash*, as used by @Eric in his answer)

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
  #=> [{ 1=>2 }, { 2=>1 }, { 3=>1 }]
```